# Symfony 2 @Route annotation case-sensitive

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

I'm trying to create a url with annotations of the route.

The problem is that I can write any URL large, small or different.

```
@Route("/{staat}/", name="showStaats",requirements={"location" = "berlin|bayern|brandenburg"})
```

This URL can be accessed both from `www.example.com/berlin` and under `www.example.com/Berlin`.

I would, however, that it is attainable only under `www.example.com/berlin`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question "How to make case-insensitive routing requirement":

You can add case-insensitive modifier to requirement regexp like so:

`(?i:berlin|bayern|brandenburg)`

Answer (score 1):

You have `"/{staat}/"`, but your requirements set `"location" = ...`, these should match, so maybe that's the cause of your problem.

If you don't want to hardcode the list of states in your route, you could inject a service containter parameter with a list of states. Just see [How to use Service Container Parameters in your Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html) in the documentation for how to do that.

If you just want to check, whether that state is all lower-cased you could try the following requirement:

```
staat: "[a-z-]+"
```

This should match only lowercase characters and dash (e.g. for "sachsen-anhalt"). But I'm not entirely sure if this will work as the router's regex-detection is a bit quirky.

You could also create a [custom Router Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) which will create routes programmatically, e.g. by fetching the list of states from a database or file.

**edit**:

As I wrote in my comment I would add the list of params as a Service Container parameter, e.g. `%my_demo.states%` containing a list of states. I'm not sure however if this will work with annotations. So here is a quick workaround how to get it working.

In your `app/config/config.yml` you append the `%my_demo.states%` parameter:

```
my_demo:
    states: ["berlin", "brandenburg", "sachsen-anhalt", ... ]
```

In your `app/config/routing.yml` there should be something like this:

```
my_demobundle:
    resource: "@MyDemoBundle/Controller/"
    prefix:   /
    type:     annotation
```

The `type: annotation` and `@MyDemoBundle` is the relevant part. Add the following route **before** this one, to make sure it takes precedence:

```
showStaats:
    path:     /{state}
    defaults: { _controller: MyDemoBundle:State:index }
    requirements:
        state: %my_demo.states%
```

This will add a route which will apply *before* your annotations using the list of states as parameters. This is a bit crude, as you are mixing yml/annotation-based routing, but it's imo still better than cramming a list of 16 states in the annotation, not to mention its easier to maintain.

Comment: I have chance it into @Route("/{location}/", name="showStaats",requirements={location: "[a-z-]+" location" = "berlin|bayern|brandenburg"}). So it does not work.

Comment: There is again a small error in your annotation (a missing comma between your 2 requirements). I don't think you can have both requirements apply at once, one will probably overwrite the other. You should use the Service Container parameter-approach I linked, since you have a fixed list of states. I will add an example to my answer...